# URL Rewrite: Prevent rewrite entirely on exising resource

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

The .htaccess file below in my root directory serves to rewrite all /api/ then outputs the key value pairs from the URL from the $_GET inside /api/api.php?

How do I modify this so that all existing files or folders inside api (such as /api/test or /api/test/file.php accessed via this scheme will not rewrite via the rewrite rule?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule (.*) $1
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1?$2=$3&%1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1/$1.php?%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following .htaccess file to include Directory index and fallback resource and placed it inside the  the root directory to catch on each request from the root.

Also I put the rewritebase /api and InheritDown option to limit where I apply these rules and also recursively propagate down to directories that exist already so they (and nested files) will not get included in the rewrite process when requested.

This produced a successful result on $_GET where there were equal numbers of lhs (key) = rhs (value) pairs in the query string provided that they were entered as /api/lhs/rhs/lhs/rhs in in the request.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex api.php
    FallbackResource index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1?$2=$3&%1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1/$1.php?%1 [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteBase /api
RewriteOptions InheritDown
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RewriteCond` directive to exclude your files and folders

```
RewriteEngine On
#if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#rewrite the /api request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1/$1.php?%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you starkeen,   should !-f read !-d for the second rerwrite condition?